# How can I calculate/estimate the resistance of the thin film structured like in the picture (top view)?

Tags: integrated-circuit, resistance, eda, physical-design

let's say the thin film is made of metal with resistivity rho and thickness t.

I need to calculate the sheet resistance between point A and B.

any reference suggestion is really appreciated.

[image: structured thin film]

Comment: can't. how far apart are the diamonds?

Comment: rough estimate: disregard the diamonds, juist calculate the 3 rectangles front-to-back. better estimate: previous one, plus 6 x the triangle with cut top from the vertical through A up to the junction with the first rectangle. Seems doable with calculus. Even better: calculate the A and B triangles up to the connection with their rectangles separately, to account for the one-point connections. No idea how to do that.

Comment: @Jasen, I edit the picture. the distance between the diamonds is h.

Comment: I think I found a way to calculate that. I will post it later.